# settings windowtitle in maximized mode in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt5.5

I want to know how to set window title in Qt in maximized mode.

```
window->setWindowtitle("window");
```

But this does not work in maximized mode.

```
playback_main *pbw = new playback_main;
pbw->setWindowTitle("PlayBack");
pbw->showMaximized();
```

This is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me on a QMainWindow in, admittedly, qt 4.7. Do you need to force an update with either of:

```
pbw->update(); 
qApp->processEvents();
```

is pbw a QMainWindow or just a widget?

I've tried the following code on linux which works too:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QMainWindow w;
  w.setWindowTitle("testing");
  w.showMaximized();
  return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: I am on Linux. Perhaps its linux system way not to show title in maximized.

Comment: I don't think that's the case. I've added an example above that works on linux no problem. what is pbw?

Comment: Sorry, I meant what is playback_main . Can you show the header, or the top of it?